# In iOS, Appium can't able to enter text into text field in WKWebview using xPath

Tags: appium, acceptance-testing, appium-ios

In iOS, Appium can't able to enter text into the text field in WKWebview using XPath(***//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Submit"]***).

I'm getting the below error.

```
**Then I tap on xPath "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Submit"]"                                                # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:467
      Error Domain=com.facebook.WebDriverAgent Code=1 "The element '"Submit" Button' is not visible on the screen and thus is not interactable" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The element '"Submit" Button' is not visible on the screen and thus is not interactable} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
      ./features/support/libs/ios.rb:1089:in `tapXpath'
      ./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:468:in `/^I tap on xPath "(.*?)"$/'
      features/wallet/add_card_3ds.feature:35:in `Then I tap on xPath "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Submit"]"'**
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can enter text into **button** element: 
`//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name="Submit"]` looks like a valid XPath locator for button, but you need to build locator for text field

Try to search for text element, probably something like

`element = find_element :class_chain, 'type = "XCUIElementTypeTextField"'`

Try not to use Xpath with Appium/iOS as it is very slow.